# Front-End Testing using Selenium WebDriver in Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, selenium-webdriver, tdd

I am working on spring mvc application and trying to test my front end as well as integration test between controller and front end using selenium web driver taking a reference from [Spring MVC test with WebDriver](http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/26/spring-mvc-test-with-webdriver). This blog suggest to use **MockMvcHtmlUnitDriver** as a web driver implementation in order to run front end test with spring mvc without deploying to server. The MVC works totally fine and **MockMvcHtmlUnitDriver** also handles request perfectly, but it doesn't gets the front end page.

Here, is a code i wrote for a test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:application-context.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WebDriverDemoTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    
    this.driver = new MockMvcHtmlUnitDriver(mockMvc, true);
}

@Test
public void testFormCreation() {

    this.driver.get("http://localhost:8080/wddemo/demo");
    System.out.println(" - Page Title: " + this.driver.getTitle());
}}
```

Here, you can see I am trying to get the page title, but these results as null.

Log of test case:

```
10:55:59,031 DEBUG TestDispatcherServlet:1218 - Rendering view      [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'spring'; URL [/spring.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
10:55:59,038 DEBUG JstlView:207 - Forwarding to resource [/spring.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'spring'
10:55:59,039 DEBUG MockRequestDispatcher:67 - MockRequestDispatcher: forwarding to [/spring.jsp]
10:55:59,039 DEBUG TestDispatcherServlet:991 - Successfully completed request
 - Page Title: null
```

In this log, you can see mvc is handled perfectly, but web driver is not getting page. However, deploying in server and using **HtmlUnitDriver** works perfectly as expected.

Do you guys see any problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your debug that you are using JSPs.

From the [part 1](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/19/introducing-spring-test-mvc-htmlunit) of the blog article you referenced:

> NOTE: Just as with Spring MVC Test, the HtmlUnit integration will work with templating technologies that do not rely on a Servlet Container (i.e. Thymeleaf, Freemarker, Velocity, etc). It does not work with JSPs since they rely on the Servlet Container.

Comment: Thank Jim I was unaware of Servlet Container.